# unable to pass -t -i options to docker on ubuntu ...am i missing something?

Tags: docker

I am just starting to learn Docker and most tutorials start with: `docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash`

I can't use it while I can do `docker run ubuntu /bin/bash`

What could I be missing ?

```
root@njain2:~# docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
docker - version 1.4
Copyright 2003, Ben Jansens <ben@orodu.net>

Usage: docker [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -help             Show this help.
  -display DISPLAY  The X display to connect to.
  -border           The width of the border to put around the
                    system tray icons. Defaults to 1.
  -vertical         Line up the icons vertically. Defaults to
                    horizontally.
  -wmaker           WindowMaker mode. This makes docker a
                    fixed size (64x64) to appear nicely in
                    in WindowMaker.
                    Note: In this mode, you have a fixed
                    number of icons that docker can hold.
  -iconsize SIZE    The size (width and height) to display
                    icons as in the system tray. Defaults to
                    24.
  -color COLOR      The background color to use for the tray.
                    Defaults to whatev
```

Answer (score 6):

You have the wrong docker installed.

You have this:  http://icculus.org/openbox/2/docker/

You want this:  https://www.docker.com/

[edit] Apparently in ubuntu the package is called docker.io not docker.

Comment: note that the docker.io Ubuntu package is outdated, prefer the following installation method: `curl -sSL https://get.docker.io/ubuntu/ | sudo sh`